# For loop in function not doing what I want

Tags: python, function, loops

I have this loop:

```
for dt in AllDates:
    data = importdata(location, dt, Curve, max_maturity = '30Y') 
    fwdrate = interpolate(data, '1y', '1y')
```

It takes each date from AllDates, imports the data for that date and then calculates a set of forward rates for said date. The forward rates are then appended in a dictionary. It does exactly what I want, no problem. However when I try turn it into a function, it doesn't run for all the dates. I'm not sure as to why this is:

```
def loop_dates(AllDates):
    for dt in AllDates:  
        data = importdata(location, dt, Curve, max_maturity = '30Y') 
        fwdrate = interpolate(data, '1y', '1y')
    return fwdrate;
```

Edit:

This is my `interpolate` code:

```py
def interpolate (dataframe, TENOR, freq):
    'Gets the forward rates from given tenors and corresponding spot rates '
    
    terms= dataframe["maturity"].tolist()
    rates= dataframe['spot rate'].tolist() 
    
    dc = ql.Actual360()
    settlement_days = 2
    
    if Curve =='3M USD' or Curve == '6M EUR' or Curve == '6M GBP': 
        
        helpers = []

        for term, r in zip(terms, rates):
            if Curve == '3M USD': 
                swapIndex = ql.UsdLiborSwapIsdaFixAm(ql.Period((term)))
                helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(r/100, swapIndex))
            elif Curve == '6M EUR':
                swapIndex = ql.EuriborSwapIsdaFixB(ql.Period((term)))
                helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(r/100, swapIndex))
            elif Curve == '6M GBP': 
                swapIndex = ql.GbpLiborSwapIsdaFix(ql.Period((term)))
                helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(r/100, swapIndex))
            
    elif Curve == 'EONIA' or Curve =='SONIA' or Curve =='FF':
       
        OIS_helpers = []
        
        if Curve == 'EONIA': 
            calendar = ql.TARGET()
            EONIA = ql.OvernightIndex("EONIA", settlement_days, ql.EURCurrency(), calendar, dc)
           
            for i in range(len(terms)):
                tenor = ql.Period(terms[i])
                rate = rates[i]
                OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), EONIA)) 
           
        elif Curve =='SONIA': 
            calendar = ql.UnitedKingdom()
            SONIA = ql.OvernightIndex("SONIA", settlement_days, ql.GBPCurrency(), calendar, dc)
            
            for i in range(len(terms)):
                tenor = ql.Period(terms[i])
                rate = rates[i]
                OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), SONIA)) 
                    
        elif Curve == 'FF': 
            calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
            FedF = ql.OvernightIndex("FedF", settlement_days, ql.USDCurrency(), calendar, dc)
            
            for i in range(len(terms)):
                tenor = ql.Period(terms[i])
                rate = rates[i]
                OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), FedF)) 
         
        helpers = OIS_helpers
    
    curve = ql.PiecewiseSplineCubicDiscount(0, ql.TARGET(), helpers, dc)
    curve.enableExtrapolation()                                                                           
    
    days = ql.MakeSchedule(curve.referenceDate(), curve.maxDate() , ql.Period(freq)) #Frequency
    
    if Curve == '3M USD' or Curve =='FF':
        fwds = [
            curve.forwardRate(d, ql.UnitedStates().advance(d,ql.Period(TENOR)), dc, ql.Simple).rate()*100
            for d in days
        ]
   
    elif Curve =='6M EUR' or Curve == 'EONIA': 
        fwds = [
            curve.forwardRate(d, ql.TARGET().advance(d,ql.Period(TENOR)), dc, ql.Simple).rate()*100 
            for d in days
        ]
    
    elif Curve =='6M GBP' or Curve == 'SONIA':
        fwds = [
            curve.forwardRate(d, ql.UnitedKingdom().advance(d,ql.Period(TENOR)), dc, ql.Simple).rate()*100
            for d in days
        ]

    dictionary = {dt:fwds} # creating a dictionary of each date, dt and its 
                           # corresponding fwds calculated, when looping over
                           #the dates, a new key-value is made
                           
    fwdsdic.update(dictionary) #adding the dictionary to a new dictionary called 
                               #fwdsdic 

    return fwdsdic;
```

Comment: What is `fwdrate` used for? Is the fact that it's being _overwritten every iteration of the loop_ to blame?

Comment: Did you passed the obj to the function correctly?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy The original code also overwrites the variable each iteration.

Comment: You need to show how you're using the loop in both versions of the program, so we can see what makes them different.

Comment: What is `fwdsdic`?

Comment: @quamrana, it's an empty dictionary that will contain all the dates and the corresponding calculated fwds

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, fwdrate will be turned into a dataframe. It shouldn't overwrite, since it doesn't do that when it's not in the function

Comment: And how do you call `loop_dates()` now?

Comment: @quamrana, USD_fwds = loop_dates(AllDates). Is this wrong?

Comment: No, its just that the `return fwdsdic` and `return fwdrate` and `USD_fwds = ...` are all redundant since `fwdsdic` is a global to start with. I can't tell what is going wrong. What does `fwdsdic` contain after the call?

Comment: Without the function loop_dates, it returns a dictionary all of the dates in AllDates and the corresponding fwd rates calculated from the interpolate function. With the function, it only gives the fwd rates for a few dates, not all of them which is what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231073/discussion-between-mike-lukos-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, I took `dictionary = {dt:fwdrate}` and `fwdsdic.update(dictionary)`  out of `interpolate` and put it outside, so now my final function is:

```
def loop_dates():
    'Runs the interpolate function for all the dates for one curve'
    for dt in AllDate:  
        data = importdata(location, dt, C, max_maturity = '30Y') 
        fwdrate = interpolate(data, '1y', '1y')
        dictionary = {dt:fwdrate} 
        fwdsdic.update(dictionary) 
    return
```